# Find Hard to Match only url from a text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

My text file consist of :

```
http://www.makemytrip.com/
http://www.makemytrip.com/blog/dil-toh-roaming-hai?intid=Blog_HPHeader_Logo   //how do i remove /dil-toh-roaming-hai?intid=Blog_HPHeader_Logo 
http://www.makemytrip.com/rewards/?intid=New_ch_mtr_na
javascript:void(0)       //how do i remove this 
javascript:void(0)
javascript:void(0)
http://www.makemytrip.com/rewards/?intid=new_ch_mtr_dropdwn
https://support.makemytrip.com/MyAccount/MyTripReward/DashBoard
https://support.makemytrip.com/MyAccount/User/User
https://support.makemytrip.com/MyAccount/MyBookings/BookingSummary/
https://support.makemytrip.com/customersupports.aspx?actiontype=PRINTETICKET
```

how do i go about checking only urls and save them in another file so that i can parse them one at a time . I tried this Python code But it matches and open the 1st url only.

```
 import urllib

 with open("s.txt","r") as file:
 for line in file:
    url = urllib.urlopen(line)
    read = url.read()
    print read
```

Comment: If this is your input, for each line, I would just check if it starts with http:
`if line.startswith('http'):`

Comment: Yes .But some links have extra which i dont want like :
`http://www.makemytrip.com/blog/dil-toh-roaming-hai?intid=Blog_HPHeader_Logo`  i want only `http://www.makemytrip.com/blog`

Comment: Do something like ``line.rsplit('/',1)[0]`` before you pass the line to ``urlopen``

Comment: thanks its working ..Yannis